# Good development board for low-level camera/imaging prototyping?

Tags: camera, development-board

I'm curious what maker/hobbyist development board is best for trying out relatively low-level image/vision processing algorithms in an embedded setting. What I mean is, I'm not interested in taking something that already comes with built-in object recognition or motion tracking and writing application-oriented "glue code" to trigger stuff when one of these built in functions "sees" something, I'm interested in actually building up mathematical operations from scratch to process pixel data in various ways, whether that be prototyping white balance correction algorithms, optical flow algorithms, face detection, or anything. The language could be anything from C to some type of shading language (if the board HAS a GPU, which I'm guessing not too many hobbyist as opposed to industrial boards do).

Answer (score 0):

Any Arduino board will be fine for you. Depend of the size of the source image (64x64 may be a challenge for most) you may need board with more memory. The language for development is similar to C. These boards are very good for automation, kind of movement detector, remote work, low power consumption.

If your intention is to work with bigger images and more sophisticated (and power consuming algorithms) probably Raspberry style boards will be better, because they can offer up to 8GB of RAM and good amount of storage. Also they usually run more powerful processors (multicore).